# How can I process results from http.get() in Angular 6/RxJS 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to upgrade an application from Angular 5 to Angular 6 and having trouble figuring out how to use RxJS's new syntax. Here's the code I'm trying to migrate:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get('assets/data/people.json');
  }

  search(q: string): Observable<any> {
    if (!q || q === '*') {
      q = '';
    } else {
      q = q.toLowerCase();
    }
    return this.getAll().map((data: any) => {
      const results: any = [];
      data.map(item => {
        // check for item in localStorage
        if (localStorage['person' + item.id]) {
          item = JSON.parse(localStorage['person' + item.id]);
        }
        if (JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(q)) {
          results.push(item);
        }
      });
      return results;
    });
  }

  get(id: number) {
    return this.getAll().map((all: any) => {
      if (localStorage['person' + id]) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage['person' + id]);
      }
      return all.find(e => e.id === id);
    });
  }

  save(person: Person) {
    localStorage['person' + person.id] = JSON.stringify(person);
  }
}
```

I know the imports should change to:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And you're supposed to use `pipe()` instead of `map()` now, but I'm having issues figuring out how. It'd be awesome if it was as simple as the following, but it doesn't seem to be.

```
    return this.getAll().pipe(
      map(data: any) => {
        const results: any = [];
        data.map(item => {
          // check for item in localStorage
          if (localStorage['person' + item.id]) {
            item = JSON.parse(localStorage['person' + item.id]);
          }
          if (JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(q)) {
            results.push(item);
          }
        });
        return results;
    }));
```

Comment: Which is the problem you encounter with this code?

Comment: you are not supposed to use pipe INSTEAD of map. you are supposed to assign the map- (and other) operation(s) to (a) variable(s) and put the variable(s) inside the pipe.

Comment: He's using pipe and map correctly here as far as I can see. :D Looked at the old and new code 15 times over and can't see anything wrong with the new code. What's the error?

Comment: Couple of other things that are wrong though they won't break the code: Using Array.prototype.map to not really map an array to a new array, rather using it as forEach. You could probably make the code cleaner by just returning the array.map result  filtered by `if item is in localStorage` first.

Comment: I see it now, a missing parentheses :)

Comment: I tried it again and you're right funkizer - it does work! Don't know why it wasn't working earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a parentheses at `map(data:any) => {}`. This should work:

```
return this.getAll().pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
        const results: any = [];
        data.map(item => {
            // check for item in localStorage
            if (localStorage['person' + item.id]) {
                item = JSON.parse(localStorage['person' + item.id]);
            }
            if (JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(q)) {
                results.push(item);
            }
        });
        return results;
    }
    )
);
```

You could do it in a more readable and functional way like this - use the Array.prototype.map function for what it's supposed to be used and add a filter:

```
return this.getAll().pipe(
    map(
        data => data
             .map(item => !!localStorage['person' + item.id]
                ? JSON.parse(localStorage['person' + item.id])
                : item)
             .filter(item => JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(q))
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks funkizer! For the more functional way, I found that I had to do the filter after the mapping to have the same functionality as before. https://github.com/mraible/ng-demo/blob/master/src/app/shared/search/search.service.ts#L23

Comment: No prob. Ah yes, i put them in wrong order. Updated answer :)